# React: check the pressed key on form submit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms, events, material-ui

I am using **React** (and Material UI), and I am trying to submit a **form**. As default by pressing **enter** when focused on the text field, the form submits. I want it to only happen when I press the **Submit** button.

The form

```
<Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
    <TextField
        margin="normal"
        required
        fullWidth
        id="title"
        label="Title"
        name="title"
        autoComplete="title"
        autoFocus
        defaultValue={title}
    />
    <TextArea setData={setData} data={JSON.parse(description)} />
    <Button
        type="submit"
        fullWidth
        variant="contained"
        sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
    >
        Finish
    </Button>
    <Link href="/">
        Back
    </Link>
</Box>
```

The submit function

```
 const handleSubmit = async (e) =>
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e)
        //
    }
```

Comment: @Dominic Is there something like e.targetkey, I just don't want to submit the form by pressing Enter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added **onKeyPress** to the TextField and checked if the pressed key is equal to Enter

```
<TextField
    margin="normal"
    required
    fullWidth
    id="title"
    label="Title"
    name="title"
    autoComplete="title"
    onKeyPress={(e) => { e.key === 'Enter' && e.preventDefault(); }} //<----
    autoFocus
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior since you have your code in a `form`. It shouldn't matter to you where the users cursor is. This is necessary for screen readers and for basic user experience.

To focus on the next field, the user should be able to tab to the next field.

`e.preventDefault` is to keep the page from reloading on submit.

Comment: But what if I want, for example by pressing enter when focused on a textfield, to focus on the next field (textarea in the example above)

Comment: That's what tab is for